# how char array length works?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I've below code snippet

```
new char[(int)floor(log(25*(n+1)) / log(26))]
```

when `n = 27`, above returns `2`

but why the length of above `char array` is `two` ?

Comment: Are you asking why `(int)floor(log(25*(n+1)) / log(26))` is `2`?

Comment: why the length of new char[(int)floor(log(25*(n+1)) / log(26))] is 2 ?

Comment: Because `log(25*(n+1)) / log(26)` is 2.01 (try with a calculator if you're unsure), [`floor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) makes it 2 (and then you cast it to `int` because otherwise you couldn't use it as an index, but that's irrelevant for the calculation)

Comment: if the outcome is only 2, that means array has only one element. But why the length of array is coming 2 ?

Comment: Size 2 means you have two elements not one. You have index 0 **and** index 1. I added a more detailed answer below, hope it helps :)

Comment: o man, am really sorry guys....my basic senses got hacked...:) I got it.!

Comment: "if the outcome is only 2, that means array has only one element" that's wrong. If the outcome is 2 that means the array has 2 elements, one at index 0 and the other at index 1. That's probably where your confusion come from.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step:

`25*(n+1) = 25 * 28 = 700`

Assuming `log` is `Math.log` which is the natural log then we have:

`log(25*(n+1)) = 6.551080335043404`

Likewise:

`log(26) = Math.log(26) = 3.258096538021482`

Therefore
`floor(log(25*(n+1)) / log(26)) = floor(6.55/3.258) = floor(2.01) = 2`

which yields `2` as expected.

In general, `char[] c = new char[n];` will make a new character array `c` with size equal to `n`. This means that there will be `n` elements in your array from indices `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: OP knows that the calculation gives 2, that is not the point.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès yep i answered before that was clarified :)